# Sonicwall NSA 3500, public ip for SSL VPN clients is not visible

Tags: vpn, sonicwall

I have a Sonciwall NSA 3500 and I'm setting up the SSL VPN according to [this guide](https://www.fuzeqna.com/sonicwallkb/consumer/kbdetail.asp?kbid=6461).

I get through setting up the Sonicwall router, but then to test it says "Users can now go to the public IP of the sonicwall. Notice the new “click here for SSL login” hyper link". However, when I go to the public ip of the Sonicwall I don't get a web page, it just times out.  Is there some other setting that I'm missing in order to make the SSL VPN login page public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it defaults to part 8080 on https. So try https://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080. And do it from OUTSIDE your network.

Comment: So the https://xx.xx.xx.xx:4433 link does work for me, but only from outside of the network like you suggest. When attempting to access from inside the network it only seems to be possible when using the router's internal ip